# How to run the "make" command for YoloV3 Darknet (for Windows)?

Tags: windows, makefile, darknet, gnuwin32

After running the ./make.exe command (By using GNUWin32), I get the following error:

```
mkdir -p obj   
mkdir -p backup   
A subdirectory or file -p already exists.  
Error occurred while processing: -p. make: *** [backup] Error 1
```

After rerunning the command, I get a different error:

```
mkdir -p results
A subdirectory or file -p already exists.
Error occurred while processing: -p.
make: *** [results] Error 1
```

Then I get the same error no matter how many times I repeat the make command:

```
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [obj/gemm.o] Error 2
```

As I am a beginner, can you please provide detailed instructions on how I can fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

These problems:

```
mkdir -p obj   
mkdir -p backup   
A subdirectory or file -p already exists.  
Error occurred while processing: -p. make: *** [backup] Error 1
```

are caused by the fact that you have asked Make to execute, on Windows,
a makefile that was written to work on Linux or some other Unix-like operating system.

In Unix-like operating systems, the command:

```
mkdir -p obj
```

means: *Create a directory called* `obj` *with no error if it already exists*. In
Windows it means: *Create a directory called* `-p` *and then a directory called* `obj`.

So when `mkdir -p obj` has created the directories `-p` and `obj`, the command:

```
mkdir -p backup
```

fails because:

```
A subdirectory or file -p already exists.
```

The Unix/Linux makefile has no intention of creating a directory called `-p`, but on Windows
that is what it does.

There is little point in your attempting to fix this specific error. It is just the
first of indefinitely many errors that will result from attempting to execute a Unix/Linux
makefile on Windows. You need a makefile that was written to run on
Windows, or to write one yourself, or to find a way of building the software on Windows that does not use Make.

This problem:

```
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [obj/gemm.o] Error 2
```

is caused by the fact that you have not installed the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org) C compiler
`gcc` on your computer, or if you have, the directory where it resides is not in your `PATH`. So Make cannot find
it to perform the essential business of compiling and linking your software.

Here is [a popular Windows port of GCC](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)

Comment: Thanks a ton for explaining in such a detailed way.
Is there any way that I can run YOLOv3 darknet in Windows that you know of?

Comment: @RedGod I don't but googling "Install YOLOv3 darknet on windows" produces hits.

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile has been written for Linux and is not directly portable to Windows.
The issue is that ‘mkdir’ is conflicting with CMD’s built-in function that doesn’t support the same command line options (as explained by Mike Kinghan).

A simple workaround is to replace any occurrence of `mkdir` in your makefile with `$(MKDIR)` and to add at the very beginning:

```
MKDIR := “$(shell which mkdir)”
```

Of course this requires that you install [which](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/which.htm) and [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) (that provides mkdir). Note the double quotes to avoid any issues with white space on the path to mkdir.

Last but not least you will also need gcc which you can get [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/) or [there](http://winlibs.com/) for example.